# determine type of next read in InputStream in java

Tags: java, file, serialization, inputstream

Assuming that there is a file with a set of primitives written in it, however I do not know the type of primitives.

How can I read the data into the appropriate data type from my code? (that is read int into int, byte into byte etc)

Or is this impossible?

Comment: It is impossible. In the end, the file is just a sequence of bytes, and nothing allows knowing that the first 4 bytes are an int, the next two ones are a char, etc. A file needs to have a well-specified format in order to be readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert it to a desired type ... if the conversion fails you try the next type and so on. The final type being a String.

For example if the file would hold those lines:

```
1
1.3
12345324223423
test
true
false
```

You can test each value if it can be converted:

```
try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(test);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    try {

        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(test);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

            ... and so on ... 
    }
}
```

I would start with the smallest and go to bigger, for instance:

- Byte
- Integer
- Long
- BigDecimal
- Boolean
- Char
- and last String